# URL rewriting problem

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

He guys,

I would like to rewrite URLs like the following one:

https://my.domain/blog/2023/09/18/newsname

to the following

https://my.domain/newsname

So, category (and maybe even subcategory) and date should simply vanish in each articles URL.

Is there a simple solution for mod_rewrite in .htaccess available?

Thx for your help,

Marcus

Comment: Have you looked in _Settings > Permalinks_? You should be able to just set it this way using the right option in settings.

Comment: Hi Jacob, this is not the problem. I would like to rewrite the URL for redirection purposes. There is this old structure which Google is aware of and I want to use a simpler scheme in future. So I want to rewrite URLs to have my old links working well, too.

Comment: Did you try changing it? The old URLs should redirect.